# configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables ERROR on FreeBSD 14.0-RELEASE

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, clang, freebsd, cc

I'm not able to install sudo on my **FreeBSD 14.0-RELEASE-p3 amd64**

```
marietto:/usr/ports/security/sudo # make

===>  License sudo accepted by the user
===>   sudo-1.9.15p4 depends on file: /usr/local/sbin/pkg - found
===> Fetching all distfiles required by sudo-1.9.15p4 for building
===>  Extracting for sudo-1.9.15p4
=> SHA256 Checksum OK for sudo-1.9.15p4.tar.gz.
===>  Patching for sudo-1.9.15p4
===>  Applying FreeBSD patches for sudo-1.9.15p4 from
/usr/ports/security/sudo/files
===>   sudo-1.9.15p4 depends on package: pkgconf>=1.3.0_1 - found
===>   sudo-1.9.15p4 depends on package: gettext-runtime>=0.22_1 - found
===>   sudo-1.9.15p4 depends on executable: msgfmt - found
===>   sudo-1.9.15p4 depends on file: /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so.12 - found
===>   sudo-1.9.15p4 depends on shared library: libintl.so - found
(/usr/local/lib/libintl.so)
===>  Configuring for sudo-1.9.15p4
configure: loading site script /usr/ports/Templates/config.site
checking for gcc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in '/usr/ports/security/sudo/work/sudo-1.9.15p4':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See 'config.log' for more details
===>  Script "configure" failed unexpectedly.

Please report the problem to garga@FreeBSD.org [maintainer] and attach the
"/usr/ports/security/sudo/work/sudo-1.9.15p4/config.log" including the output
of the failure of your make command. Also, it might be a good idea to provide
an overview of all packages installed on your system (e.g. a
/usr/local/sbin/pkg-static info -g -Ea).
*** Error code 1

Stop.
make[1]: stopped in /usr/ports/security/sudo
*** Error code 1

Stop.
make: stopped in /usr/ports/security/sudo
```

More informations are located here :

**/usr/local/sbin/pkg-static info -g -Ea** =

https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/3fCY3hFRCG/

**/usr/ports/security/sudo/work/sudo-1.9.15p4/config.log** =

https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/PK2QxNHwkk/

I suspect some misconfiguration on the gcc / cc / clang compiler.

I expect that sudo won't be installed telling that it has been already installed from packages,but the error is different.

Comment: Without knowing the history of your system, it's hard to say what is going on here ; for sure, `cc` is not working as expected ; at least, check if cc could be found: `cc -v`